# set verbose logging for ProFTPd

Tags: logging, verbose, proftpd

Proftpd 1.3.5e Server on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

How do I set up verbose logging for ProFTPd such that the ftp USER and filename and IP address and timestamp all show up on one line?  For each file name uploaded and/or downloaded?  One line per file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways you might achieve this.  The easiest is to configure a [`TransferLog`](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/modules/mod_core.html#TransferLog) directive in your `proftpd.conf`:

```
TransferLog /var/log/proftpd/xfer.log
```

The format of this log file is *fixed*; see [`xferlog(5)`](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Logging.html#TransferLog) for details.  But the format does include the fields you requested.

Alternatively, you can use ProFTPD's more sophisticated [`LogFormat`](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/modules/mod_log.html#LogFormat) directive to specify your own log format, and then the [`ExtendedLog`](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/modules/mod_log.html#ExtendedLog) directive to *use* that `LogFormat` for writing to a specific file, *e.g.*

```
LogFormat custom "%{iso8601} %u %f %a"
ExtendedLog /var/log/proftpd/custom.log READ,WRITE custom
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: weet! Perfect! Works like a charm! I used your second suggestion and it works right out of the box. I realize this was not part of the original ask, but the first upload I tested with this failed with permission denied because I was uploading onto a file owned by root. Is there a % letter that describes the status of the request in the logfile? Failed or success?

Comment: There is the `%{transfer-status}` LogFormat variable for the transfer status; see the [`LogFormat`](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/modules/mod_log.html#LogFormat) docs for the full list of supported variables.